# What is the "learn" tag good for?

Tags: discussion, tags

Could someone tell me the pro's of having [learn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/learn)? Some questions are closed (as dupe, 1 NARQ). The others are very subjective (where do I start?), or too broad (asking for *"good"* books), instead asking questions that really have an answer. I say the tag has to go and the questions that aren't questions being closed accordingly.

Seems that there is consensus. Anyone up for the task?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/learn

Comment: I agree ; it's not a good tag.

Comment: I also agree to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No more learn tag.

This tag has been removed :D

Comment: You're supposed to use [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/M2qer.png) :)

Comment: [What about these?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/learn)

Comment: @jokerdino I swear they weren't there D: